# What is difference between (CIL or MSILor IL) with CTS?

Tags: c#, .net

i read about `CIL` and `CTS` and both show me that a thing between source code and CLR , and also both show me that for example `integer` from `VB` and `int` from `C#`  will eventually become Int32.

and now , I do not understand what is difference between `CIL` and `CTS` ؟

Comment: CTS is just the type system.  CIL, MSIL and IL are all the same thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997605/cil-cls-and-cts-in-net

Comment: I accept but do they both do the type conversion? I do not understand this for example : `Integer` and `int` to `Int32`

Comment: That isn't a conversion. Those are all the same thing by different names.

Comment: @Amy I think I realized, thanks.